# HoloLens: Spatial awareness in dynamic environments

Tags: hololens, mrtk, slam

My Hololens 2 application requires the system to disregard some basic changes in the environment after a hologram has been placed. Sometimes these changes are in close proximity to the hologram, i.e. the physical surface below the hologram shifts laterally while everything else in the room remains constant, or a physical object is registered with the hologram. Currently, these changes tend to cause my hologram to drift. Should I, after placing the hologram, simply turn off the spatial mesh observer in my MRTK? This is a fundamental issue about spatial awareness that I don't understand; how does spatial awareness works in dynamic environments, particularly when you want to ignore certain aspects that are changing. I appreciate any advice - I'm a clinician not a developer so much of this is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

The following link is probably the place to start to inform yourself [Coordinate systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/mixed-reality/coordinate-systems).

Fortunately or rather unfortunately the problem you describe is mentioned in chapter "Headset tracks incorrectly due to dynamic changes in the environment". Apparently there is just the suggestion to use it in a less dynamic environment.

To effectively address this problem, one would probably need an AI algorithm that recognizes and responds to complex changes in space. However, this is only a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had seen that page where it discusses using a less dynamic environment. Obviously, that was not encouraging. I also read about Mesh Caching here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/spatial-mapping where it discusses how to handle surface updates. That's what got me thinking about turning of the spatial observer. Still doesn't quite make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

We recommend  that using [Spatial Anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/coordinate-systems#spatial-anchors) to locate the hologram you placed.
The Spatial Anchor marks important points in the world to ensure that anchored holograms stay precisely in place.

If you are using this technology, you should note the locations where you create anchors should have stable visual features(that is, features that don't change often). For example, the physical surface you mentioned shifting laterally is not a good point to create anchors. But a static position with stable visual features around that physical surface would be a good point.

If you are new to the Spatial Anchor, you can start from here: [Spatial Anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/spatial-anchors)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will look into spatial anchors. Currently, I use Vuforia to place the hologram precisely. I'm not sure if I can get that some type of placement accuracy using a spatial anchor.